# File splitting and encryption

Tags: file, encryption, file-recovery, filesplitting

I have a file ( an image, an audio , a video, an txt file)

1: I need to slit that file in to "n" part and encrypt them

2: if some part of "n"  let make it "a " is missing I can use "n-a" to recover and decrypt to get the data point from the beginning.

thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.